# How to disable right clicking mathjax in shiny

Tags: shiny, mathjax

How to disable right clicking mathjax in shiny? For example, see

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html

Ideally, I would like users not to be abe to interact with the mathjax text at all.

Answer (score 9):

You can turn off the MathJax contextual menu by adding

```
<script type="tet/x-mathjax-config">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  showMathMenu: false
});
</script>
```

to your page just *before* the script that loads MathJax.js itself.

I would encourage you not to do this, however.  There are important functions in the menu, including the controls for those using assistive technology like screen readers.  Those users may need access to those controls to set things appropriately for their assistive needs.  If you disable the menu, you may prevent them from being able to use your pages.

Comment: It did not work on my local hosting of MathJax. I downloaded the code from `GitHub` as explained [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/hosting.html#getting-mathjax-via-git) and linked my html file as explained [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/hosting.html#linking-to-you-your-copy-of-mathjax). Added your above script just before the `<script src="path-to-MathJax/tex-chtml.js" id="MathJax-script" async></script>`. The Math displays nicely but the Context Menu is still there. Is that github download MathJax version 3.0? Or what could be the issue? Using `file:///` not server.

Comment: @nam, You are using version 3.0, so you need to use the answer from Constructor below.

Answer (score 3):

In case of *MathJax 3* [use the following syntax](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/upgrading/v2.html#v2-contextual-menu-changes):

```
MathJax = {
  options: {
    renderActions: {
      addMenu: []
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

a little CSS rule

```
mjx-container.MathJax {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```